# Android get event onUserInteraction

Tags: android, events

I'm looking to save all events due to user interaction in my app ( for debug and session replaying purposes).
I found that onUserInteraction would trigger everytime a user interaction happens that's exactly what i need .
But is it possible to get the event that triggered it ?

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction(){
    System.out.println("print event object");
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class **debugTrigger** in which you put a boolean value for every component you want to monitor

For example:

```
class debugTrigger{

   public static boolean button1 = false;
   public static boolean button2 = false;
   .
   .
}
```

And every time for example the button 1 is pressed, in his **onClick** function you put **debugTrigger.bottom1=true**

So doing in onUserInteraction() you can do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction(){
  if(debugTrigger.buttom1)
     .... do something
     debugTrigger.buttom1 = false; //reset to false
  if(debugTrigger.buttom2)
     .... do something
     debugTrigger.buttom2 = false; //reset to false
  .
  .
}
```